# While read line do and append to a file

Tags: shell

I'm getting confused by this script that I am trying to write. Any help would be appreciated, I searched around and wasn't able to come up with a solution. I'm sure it's right in front of my eyes.

I have a python script that makes an API call which returns a value. I have a file (examplefile.txt) where I would like to submit each of the lines to the python script and save the returned text in test.txt

Here is what I came up with, but isn't working. The script appears to run correctly, and I see all of my submitted values from the exampleFile.txt, but nothing is being saved to the test.txt file

```
cat exampleFile.txt | while read line; do ./apiCall.py -v $line | cut -f2 -d, > test.txt |; done
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

ANSWERED THANKS!:

```
cat exampleFile.txt | while read line; do ./apiCall.py -v $line | cut -f2 -d, >> test.txt |; done
```

Also could use

```
while read line; do ./apiCall.py -v $line | cut -f2 -d; done < exampleFile.txt >> test.txt
```

Comment: Why not use Python to open the file ("exampleFile.txt"), read its lines and then call the API in apiCall.py with that. That would be easier to not only debug, but also easier to read.

Comment: I originally wrote the python to submit single entries. I am shoehorning it to run multiples with this script. I didn't want to have to change the python code if possible. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shell scripting question more than it is a python one.     However, I think your issue is  "  > test.txt"   the ">" will start from a blank file each time instead of appending the results.  try  " >> test.txt"